Usage of UNION DISTINCT in clickhouse-sqlalchemy
I would like to execute a couple of select queries using UNION DISTINCT statement.
As ClickHouse docs says I should provide ALL or DISTINCT keywords, or set union_default_mode previously.
But I can not find possibility to provide some of keywords. Clickhouse-sqlalchemy docs mentions about UNION only in this section and provide example of using sqlalchemy built-in expression union_all. It`s usefull but how to execute UNION DISTINCT?
I see only way to set union_default_mode before my query. Does exist way to add keword to UNION with some of sqlalchemy tools, or probably I missed something in clickhouse-sqlalchemy documentation?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To execute a UNION DISTINCT query using SQLAlchemy with ClickHouse, you indeed need to use the union() function instead of union_all(). However, ClickHouse's support for UNION DISTINCT might not be directly exposed through the SQLAlchemy ClickHouse dialect.
Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:
Set the union_default_mode before executing your query: You can set the union_default_mode to distinct for your session or query.

Use raw SQL for complex queries: If you need to use the UNION DISTINCT explicitly and SQLAlchemy does not support it directly, you can fallback to using raw SQL execution.

An example demonstrating both approaches:
Approach 1: Setting union_default_mode before your query
You can set the union_default_mode to distinct for the session:
`from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

# Create your engine
engine = create_engine('clickhouse://default:@localhost/default')

# Set the union_default_mode to distinct
with engine.connect() as connection:
connection.execute(text("SET union_default_mode = 'distinct'"))

# Now you can run your UNION query
result = connection.execute(text("""
    SELECT column1 FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT column1 FROM table2
"""))

for row in result:
    print(row)`

Approach 2: Using raw SQL for complex queries
If setting the mode globally isn't desirable, you can use raw SQL directly for your specific query:
`from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

# Create your engine
engine = create_engine('clickhouse://default:@localhost/default')

with engine.connect() as connection:
# Directly execute the UNION DISTINCT query
result = connection.execute(text("""
    SELECT column1 FROM table1
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT column1 FROM table2
"""))

for row in result:
    print(row)`

Approach 3: Using SQLAlchemy ORM and Union Function
If you prefer to stick to ORM, you can create a UNION DISTINCT query by using SQLAlchemy's union():
`from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, union
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Assuming you have a Table object
from your_model import Table1, Table2

# Create your engine
engine = create_engine('clickhouse://default:@localhost/default')

# Create a configured "Session" class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# Create a Session
session = Session()

# Create your queries
query1 = select(Table1.c.column1)
query2 = select(Table2.c.column1)

# Use the union function for UNION DISTINCT
combined_query = union(query1, query2)

# Execute the query
result = session.execute(combined_query)

for row in result:
print(row)`

Note: The union() function in SQLAlchemy generates a UNION DISTINCT by default.
Ensure that your SQLAlchemy ClickHouse dialect supports these operations. If not, the raw SQL approach will be your best bet for running more complex queries that require specific SQL syntax not directly supported by the ORM.

"ClickHouse's support for UNION DISTINCT might not be directly exposed through the SQLAlchemy ClickHouse dialect" - either it is or it is not. Can you be specific?

Thank you for your response. I mentioned approach using setting union_default_mode before query and asked something else approach. And unfortunately SQLAlchemy union() does not generate UNION DISTINCT by default, but generates simply UNION, that causes error on ClickHouse side if union_default_mode was not set (according to documentation).
